# Validate string given Context Free Grammar in Java

Tags: java, parsing, computer-science, context-free-grammar, formal-languages

How can someone validate if a string is part of a context free Grammar? Not just virtually, but build an algorithm for it?

Given a context free grammar with rules such as

- V-> v1v2
- v1->1 | 1v1
- v2-> 2 | 2v2

It is obvious that this is the language 1^n 2^n. But how would you go about with an algorithm to verify if it actually is. I am trying to accomplish this in java.

Comment: Do you want to verify that a string is generated by a CFG, or that the language of the CFG is what you say it is?

Comment: If the string is valid, meaning it belongs to the context free language, whose context free grammar is provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to look into [Earley's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser) or the [CYK algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm), which are two algorithms for deciding whether a string is generated by a context-free grammar.  Earley's algorithm runs in time O(n<sup>3</sup>) for any string of length n regardless of the production rules in the grammar (though the constant term in the big-O notation depends on the grammar), while the CYK algorithm requires that the grammar first be converted to [Chomsky normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form) to guarantee O(n<sup>3</sup>) runtime.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah it helps a lot. One more question related to your answer. Is it even possible to implement epsilon transitions?

Comment: Given that there is an equivalence between NFA with ε-moves and regular NFA's, the answer would be "yes is possible".  Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton_with_%CE%B5-moves

Comment: @StephenC- NFAs and DFAs are formalisms for regular languages, not context-free languages.